# Como fazer um redirecionamento de entrada (equivalente ao "<" no Linux) com PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

No Linux, quando queremos fazer um redirecionamento de saída, utilizamos o símbolo `>`.

```
 echo "Olá mundo" > Hello.txt
```

Fiz o teste acima no PowerShell e obtive o mesmo resultado.

Acontece que, quando precisei importar um SQL via linha de comando, não consegui fazer a mesma coisa que faço no Linux ao usar o "redirecionamento de entrada".

```
mysql -u root database_name < /caminho/para/o/arquivo.sql
```

Como é que faço para fazer esse redirecionamento de entrada no PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja se isto resolve para você:

```
Get-Content /caminho/para/o/arquivo.sql | mysql -u root database_name
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Other/GetContent.ps).

Você inverte a situação, pega o conteúdo e manda para um comando fazendo um *piping*.

Answer (score 1):

Como **alternativa** você poderia usar o próprio `mysql-client` para isto:

```
mysql -u root database_name
mysql> tabela /caminho/para/o/arquivo.sql
```

Comment: Interessante. Agradeço pela resposta, mas nesse caso a intenção foi fazer uma perggunta genérica sobre o assunto.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters por isto mesmo escrevi "como alternativa", eu ia responder algo parecido com o do Maniero, como ele foi mais rapido eu apaguei o começo da minha resposta e deixei somente a parte alternativa :P